# will the Jvm load a class file twice?

Tags: java

Suppose i have a file called A.java, when i compile it it makes a A.class now assume that i have opened two command prompts and at a time i'm hitting the command java A in both this commandprompt. will the jvm load the class twice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no "the" JVM: you are starting two separate processes with their own heap, classloader, etc. The class will load twice, once in each JVM, separate from the other.

Comment: BTW, just to elaborate on the subject, had @Reuben used the same JVM, and not two different ones, he could still have loaded the exact same class twice - into two different classloader contexts

Comment: @Yaneeve - you are assuming the existence of some mechanism that *allows* you to do this; i.e. run an applications twice in the same JVM from the command prompt.  Since this is hypothetical, we can't predict how it would be implemented.

Comment: @Yaneeve makes a good point. While the question as posed has a straightforward answer, a casual reader could make the inference that if there were only one instance of the JVM the answer would be different. It is not.

Comment: Even loading the same class twice in the same JVM requires a little legwork, defining a new classloader and using slightly different syntax to load the class in it vs. compile-time references or using the default classloader. I have done this before, once, in a very unique and specific circumstance that required it. Normally there is not much of a use for loading the same class twice.

Answer (score 2):

If you run the java command in two command prompts, two JVMs would be created and your class will be loaded into each JVM's classloader separately.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the class would be loaded twice.

Answer (score 2):

Also, class may be loaded more then once into a single JVM, but with different classloader hierarchies.